# How to filter rows based on input param in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having big time problem writing this query.

If my sample data looks like this ...

```
id   Fruit name     Group      Type
-----------------------------------------
1    Orange         Citrus     null
2    Mango          Sweet      null
3    Red chilly     Hot        null
4    Green chilly   Hot        null
5    Green chilly   Hot        Organic 1
6    Green chilly   Hot        Organic 2
```

I would like to create a stored procedure which accepts a `@FoodType` parameter.

- When `@FoodType` is passed as `NULL`, the SP should return rows `1, 2, 3` and `4`.
- If `@FoodType` is `Organic 2`, then the SP should return `1, 2, 3` and `6`.

In my table, `FruitName` and `Type` columns can potentially make a compound unique key, but I did not create one though.

What's the best approach to write this kind of queries?

Update:
When 'Organic 2' is passed, since **Type** is not defined for row 4, row 6 takes precedence over row 4.

Comment: maybe the `NULL` can be of any type.

Comment: I think that he wants to return 1,2, 3, 4 and 6 when 'Organic 2' is passed..

Comment: @marc_s - It makes some sense if he wants to get all the things that match they input and null otherwise

Comment: Updated the question. The query, I think, won't be too easy.

Comment: FWIW - the awkwardness of these queries suggest you might want to redesign your tables

Comment: Actually I have simplify my problem for purpose of easy understanding. The design is correct, the example I took might have made little sense. But thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you're on SQL Server **2005** or newer (you didn't mention that...):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetFoods(@FoodType VARCHAR(20))
AS
    ;WITH Data AS
    (
        SELECT
            id, FruitName, GroupName, FruitType,
            RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FruitName ORDER BY FruitType DESC)
        FROM dbo.Fruits
        WHERE (FruitType IS NULL OR FruitType = @FoodType)
    )
    SELECT 
        id, FruitName, GroupName, FruitType
    FROM Data
    WHERE RowNo = 1
```

This seems to do what you're looking for in my case.

If you pass in `NULL`, you get back rows `1, 2, 3` and `4`

```
EXEC dbo.GetFoods @FoodType = NULL
```

[image]

and if you call it using `Organic 2`, you get back:

```
EXEC dbo.GetFoods @FoodType = 'Organic 2'
```

[image]

Comment: Cant believe you have a working example of it with my data!! You are awesome. Appreciate your time, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear; anyway, considering that you want to return `1,2, 3, 4 and 6` when `'Organic 2'` is passed,
you could creathe this stored. It will returns the fields where is `NULL`, and also, if the parameter is `not NULL`, will filter with that criteria.

```
create procedure dbo.YourProcedureName
(
@FoodType varchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
select
id,Fruit, name, Group,Type 
from yourTable where Type IS NULL or Type = @FoodType 
END
```

Comment: No. I just want rows 1, 2, 3 and 6.